# SSIS Custom Task with a default Task UI

Tags: ssis, installation, ssis-2012

I followed the tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506223010/https://linchpinpeople.com/creating-a-custom-ssis-2012-task-binding-the-task-and-editor/) to build a very simple task and was able to get that task to work.

Here are my current tools:

- Sql Server 2012
- Visual Studio 2013 (project is compiled in .net 4.0)
- Sql Server Data Tools (from Sql Server 2012)

What I want to do, however, is use the default IU with the property window that you see inside Sql Server Data Tools.  [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS) is a tutorial to do so, but it is quite old.

The problem I seem to be having is that I can't seem to locate Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.  I tried adding the compatibility tools, but that did not bring the dll into my GAC.

I would really like to be able to pull in that dll and use `DTSBaseTaskUI` so that I can inherit the default look of the UI within Sql Data Tools without recreating the already used UI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever got this solved, but I was able to find it in the GAC:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls\...\Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.DLL
```

Let me know if that did the trick for you